# data-popup: lightbox cant popup with error (Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:image/jpeg;base64)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, popup, laravel-8, lightbox

[my table with the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0rip.png)
.. I have a problem, my image won't appear in the popup, i use `data-popup:lightbox`.
My code:

```
<td>
  <a href="${data.trRadFoto}" data-popup="lightbox">
     <img src="${data.trRadFoto}" width="50px" alt="" class="img-preview rounded">
  </a>
</td>
```

i got an error:

> Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:image/jpeg;base64,

Comment: Please add relevant code andwhat you have tried.

Comment: @DreamBold tag <a href="${data.trRadFoto}" data-popup="lightbox"> doesnt work

Comment: Can you add your full HTML/js code? or can you replicate your issue on codepen? https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/yLqNPxP